# App.use is not a function error in Express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a seperate file that will hold all the modules that I'm using in the project. But it is giving me `app.use is not a function` error.

I'v been spending alot of time on this. So, I just wanted to know if this is even possible.

Code that I have tried so far.

**index.js**

```
const requireModules = require("./require");

for (let keys in requireModules) {
   app.use(keys);
}
```

**Require.js**

```
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");

module.exports = {
   cors: cors(),
   morgan: morgan("common"),
   helmet: helmet(),
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an app instance before invoking `app.use()`:

```
const requireModules = require("./require");
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); // app instance.

Object.values(requireModules).forEach(lib => app.use(lib));
```

Comment: Yes those were already set. I was using Object.keys instead of Object.values. Thanks man <3